# jquery getting this child to change img src

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, find, rollover

There's an old method I've used a lot to append a "-rollover" to an img to save me a lot of css rules but I've come across an instance where I can't get it to work.

Usually I just give the img a class of rollover and then use this jQuery:

```
$(".rollover").hover(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").split(".").join("-rollover."));
}, function() {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").split("-rollover.").join("."));
});
```

However in this case the img is sitting in an element and I want the hover of the element to change the img src.

Here's a sample of the HTML:

```
<li class="rollover-child grid-item-2">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="img/copy/file.jpg" width="231" height="130" />
        <span class="gl-grid-text">
            <span class="gl-grid-title">Book!</span>
            <span class="gl-grid-sub-text">View upcoming events</span>
            <span class="gl-grid-arrow">&gt;</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

There are also some list items which don't have an anchor but still need the rollover effect, eg

```
<li class="rollover-child>
    <img src="img/copy/file.jpg" width="231" height="130" />
</li>
```

The jQuery I was trying was this:

```
$(".rollover-child").hover(function() {
    $('img', this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").split(".").join("-rollover."));
}, function() {
    $('img', this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").split("-rollover.").join("."));
});
```

but I can't get it to work at all. I've tried variations with find and children and siblings but I must be doing something wrong.

Any help hugely appreciated.

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: Shouldn't `$(this).attr("src").split(".").join("-rollover.")` be like `$('img', this).attr("src").split(".").join("-rollover.")` as `this` here is still referring to the `li` tag which doesn't has a `src` attribute!!

Comment: Vishal I think that using $('img', this) is the same as doing $(this).find(img)

Comment: Yes right! but when you're setting the `src` attribute you should refer to the same selector; as you still need to refer to the same *img* tag. so instead of `$(this)` you should try `$('img', this)`

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood which $(this) you were referring to! Sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
$(".rollover-child").hover(function() {
    $('img', this).attr("src", function(index, currentAttributeValue){
       return currentAttributeValue.split(".").join("-rollover.");
    });
}, function() {
    $('img', this).attr("src", function(index, currentAttributeValue){
       return currentAttributeValue.split("-rollover.").join(".");
    });
});
```

<sub>See [.attr( attributeName, function(index, attr) )](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)</sub>

Comment: Is there a problem using $('img', this).attr("src", $('img', this).attr("src").split(".").join("-rollover."));

I don't really understand the usage of currentAttributeValue

Comment: @alexleonard Yes, see my comment under the `sushanth reddy`'s answer. You can test it. Just add 2 different `img`'s inside of the `.rollover-child` element. And you can see the problem.

Comment: Ahhh, very nice. Thanks for the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case **$(this)**  corresponds to   to `<li class="rollover-child>`  and you are trying to access the `$(this).attr("src")`  which is wrong .. You need to target the image here.

Try this

```
 $(".rollover-child").hover(function() {
    $('img', this).attr("src", $(this).find('img').attr("src").split(".").join("-rollover."));
}, function() {
    $('img', this).attr("src", $(this).find('img').attr("src").split("-rollover.").join("."));
});
```

Comment: If there will be multiple `img`s inside of the `.rollover-child` element, all `img`s will have the `src` value of the first `img` element. This `$(this).find('img').attr("src")` is the `src` of the first `img` element.

Comment: that does it too, as mentioned by Vishal in the question comments

Comment: $('img', this).attr("src", $('img', this).attr("src").split(".").join("-rollover.")); would also work then